# What is the class(data type) of "tf" in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, types, terminology

In MATLAB, transfer functions are also used and for that purpose tf command is availabe

When using whos command to get data type of transfer function, it returns type as tf

But when trying to study about fundamental MATLAB classes from MATHWORKS website at link below, i am unable to find "tf" data type there, is it included in any other data type?

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/fundamental-matlab-classes.html

Comment: You are right, the `tf` data type is not a fundamental class. It is a specific class used to capture properties and methods relevant to transfer functions. For example, the [`step`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lti.step.html) method gives the step response associated with a transfer function. You can find more information about this class [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/tf.html)

Comment: I would also mention that if you need to see properties of the class, you can use `properties(tf)` and if you need to see available functions, you can use `methods(tf)`.  These will provide lists of the accessible properties and usable functions for transfer function objects.